# Play local mp3 file using AUGraph and NSInputStream

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode

I'm wondering whether it is possible to stream a local mp3 file using `AUGraph` and `NSInputStream`. I have not found any good examples. The only reliable example I've found is [StreamingKit](https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit), but it is very complicated.

A working swift example would be a perfect answer. All the useful information is also welcome:

- What kind of `AUNode` should be used, what are proper `AudioComponentDescription`
- Should I use `AudioFileStreamOpen`, how to create `PropertyListenerProc` in swift3

There is my code ([stream](http://paste.org.ru/?ef6apl), [graph](http://paste.org.ru/?ojf0gv)), but I'm stuck and don't know where to go further. So, any help is appreciated.